# Why a Query Is Not Added to the Cache in OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

Some cases query results do not insert in the cache where the  logical sql query was suppose to insert into the cache. As a result, frequently cache missed occurs. Would anyone please explain the reasons for not insert a query result into the obiee12c cache.

Answer (score 0):

The following describes some situation when this might occur

1. Noncacheable SQL element.
2. Noncacheable table.
3. Cache hit
4. Result set is too big.
5. Query is cancelled

More details please go through the following document.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIESG/configfileref.htm#BIESG357